# Django: How to add comments under post

Tags: django

I have trouble adding comments under my posts on the website I'm creating using Django.

This is my **story.html** file, which is supposed to show the story title, the story itself, all the comments of the story and give users the ability to add a new comment. Although the form is shown, it is not usable. Even though I have added comments to the stories manually through admin, none of them is shown.

```
{% extends "pinkrubies/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="post-preview">
        <h2 class="post-title"> {{ story.title }}</h2>
        <p class="post-subtitle">
            {{ story.story }}
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="post-preview">
        {% for com in latest_comments %}
            <div class="post-preview">
                <p class="post-subtitle"> {{ comment.com }} </p>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% if user_id %}
    <div class="post-preview">
        <form action="{% url 'pinkrubies:story' user.id story.id %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <p class="post-title">
                    Comments
                </p>
                <textarea id="text" name="text"class="form-control" placeholder="Comment" rows="4">{{ comment.com }}
                </textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Submit </button>
        </form>
    </div>
    {% else %}
        <p class="post-meta">You must have an account to comment. <a href="{% url 'pinkrubies:login' %}"> Log in</a> or <a href="{% url 'pinkrubies:register' %}"> Register</a></p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```
def story_view(request, user_id, story_id):
    latest_comments = Comment.objects.order_by('-date')
    if story_id is not None:
        story = get_object_or_404(Story, pk=story_id)
    else:
        story = Story()
        story.user_id = user_id
    if request.method == 'POST':
        story.title = request.post.get('title')
        story.story = request.post.get('story')
        story.date = timezone.now()
        story.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('pinkrubies:story', args=(user_id,)))
    else:
        context = {
            'user_id': user_id,
            'story_id': story_id,
            'title': story.title,
            'story': story,
            'comments': story.comments,
            'latest_comments': latest_comments
        }
    return render(request, 'pinkrubies/story.html', context)


def comment_view(request, comment, user_id):
    latest_comments = Comment.objects.order_by('-date')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment.com = request.POST['com']
        comment.date = timezone.now()
        comment.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('pinkrubies:story', args=(user_id,)))
    else:
        context = {'latest_comments': latest_comments}
    return render(request, 'pinkrubies/story.html', context)
```

I am aware I have added the "latest_comments" in both views, I did that to see if any of it works and it doesn't. I'm not even sure that the comment_view is needed.

Also, when I try to submit a comment, this error is thrown:

> AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'post'

in story_view `story.title = request.post.get('title')`

Any help is welcome! 
Thank you !!!

Comment: There are multiple errors at multiple places. consider referring to django - writing your first app and completing the tutorial. It gives considerable amount of information in relatively less time. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you want to get something from POST, you should use `request.POST.get('title')`; although I would rather use a Form and let it handle the request.

At a first glance, this:

```
{% for com in latest_comments %}
    <div class="post-preview">
        <p class="post-subtitle"> {{ comment.com }} </p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Sould be

```
{% for comment in latest_comments %}
    <div class="post-preview">
        <p class="post-subtitle"> {{ comment.com }} </p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

In your code, you're using `com` to iterate through `latest_comments`, yet you try to use comment to access com attribute (not sure how your Comment model looks like though)

Answer (score 1):

It's accessed via `request.POST`. WSGIRequest object does not have a `post` field it has `POST` field.

Also, you are not sending the fields you are attempting to read from request.

```py
...
story.title = request.POST.get('title')
story.story = request.POST.get('story')
...
```

only field you are sending is called text and it should be accessed like this

```
text = request.POST.get('text')
```

also template has more errors please check your code once again.

Comment: you are right, I will look more into it, thank you :)